# Accessing array in MASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I've got the address of my array (passed as a pointer to the function) in esi register. How can I access a particular cell of the array? i.e:

```
my_array[a + b * c]
```

where `c` is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up instructions such as [LEA](http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/lea.htm)

Think of it this way:

```
LEA edx,[esi+ebx*4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could directly move it as follows also:

```
MOV EDX, [ESI + 4*EBX]
```

For a static array, you can actually use two registers at once to index it, but using the array base address as the 32-bit displacement in [the addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes).  This only works for non-position-independent code.

```
MOV EDX, my_array[ECX + 4*EBX]
```

Instead of using two different registers, you can use the same register twice to simulate a scale factor of 3 (`ebx + ebx*2`), 5, or 9.